# Application.yml values gets converted to lower case automatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I am using spring-boot.

I have this property file.

application.yml:

```
auth:
  bypass: TRUE
```

Class:

```
  @Value("${auth.bypass}")
  private String bypass;
```

I would expect to see the value for bypass to be equal to `TRUE`. However, when I am debugging and stepping through, i see that my value is in lower case `true`.

Can I know why and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the value in quotes then you will get as it is. like

```
auth:
  bypass: 'TRUE'
```